# How to fetch a protion of xml in java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, unmarshalling

My requirement is to fetch all the things in between particular tag in xml.
What are the possible ways of doing this?

for example my xml looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <class>
    <teacher>
        <subject>English</subject>
    </teacher>
   <student rollno="393">
      <firstname>dinkar</firstname>
      <lastname>kad</lastname>
      <nickname>dinkar</nickname>
      <marks>85</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="493">
      <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
      <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
      <nickname>vinni</nickname>
      <marks>95</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="593">
      <firstname>jasvir</firstname>
      <lastname>singh</lastname>
      <nickname>jazz</nickname>
      <marks>90</marks>
   </student>
</class>
```

So how can I get the all the things in between `<teacher>` tag

Comment: Please provide more information : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: **Your edit is still insufficient, and your reopen request should be denied.**  You need to show more than XML.  There are many references available for parsing XML in Java.  Use one, and return with a specific question with specific code.  Read [ask].

Comment: What would you like as the output of your code?

Answer (score -1):

seems like [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) will be a good fit or you

Comment: XPath is definitely the answer, but you should include an example that selects what the question asks (now that it's been edited).